# How do I bake a normal Map in Blender?

Tags: blender, normals, shading

I try to bake a normal Map but everything is not working. So I watched a tutorial and followed it and it still doesnt work at all.

I simply created a plane with some deformation and a simple plane for the baking. I UV unrapped both, created a new image texture, selected it in the Shading Nodes, selected the High Poly and then the Low Poly Plane and starked baking it, but I always get a flat normal map with nothing on it, for every object I try. Does anyone has a tip, an idea or any other tutorial for this?
Thank you

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then check the [help/on-topic] to see which questions are on-topic on this site.
You might want to delete this question and ask it on https://blender.stackexchange.com/ instead, but check the help pages there first.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.